# Enable Laravel Debugbar in AppServiceProvider behavior

Tags: laravel, debugging, service-provider, phpdebugbar

I found this [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) I would like to use in my app.
But I want to enable it based on a condition. I tried adding my code in both register() and boot() method in the AppServiceProvider, where I put all other similar checks, but both don't work.

When changing the DEBUGBAR_ENABLED in the config, everything works as it should.
So I've set the default to `false` and want to enable it only dynamically.
However, I just can't understand why the following happens:

With this code the debugbar works:

```
public function boot()
{
    \Debugbar::enable();
}
```

With this code the debugbar throws 404 errors and doesn't work when the condition is met:

```
public function boot()
{
    if (isset($_GET['debug']) && $_GET['debug'] === 'debugbar') {
        \Debugbar::enable();
    }
}
```

If anyone has an idea why this is happening, please explain!

Comment: to confirm, your url looks like this? /?debug=debugbar

Comment: @josezenem Yes.

Comment: I suspect there is something else at play because I cant see how it would work differently if you put `if(1){ \Debugbar::enable(); }`

Comment: @Flame if (true) works, if ($_GET) too, but if i check something in $_GET, then it happens.

Comment: @Annity do a dd($_GET) with values, are those the expected values you have in the url?

Comment: @josezenem Yes. array:1 [▼
  "debug" => "debugbar"
]